# The style.css stylesheet doesn’t contain a valid theme header. what should I do, please?

Tags: themes

when I try to upload a theme I have uploaded on a free host and it is the first time I upload a theme on a host, I got this error failed because The style.css stylesheet doesn’t contain a valid theme header.

then I put this on my styles.css , but still getting this error , although the theme works very well on the localhost. what should I do, please?

```
/**
* Template Name: Mamba - v4.0.1
* Template URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/mamba-one-page-bootstrap-template-free/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
* License: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# General
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead:

```css
/**
 * Theme Name: Mamba
 * Theme URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/mamba-one-page-bootstrap-template-free/
 * Author: BootstrapMade
 * Author URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/
 * Version: 4.0.1
 * License URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
 */
```

Or something like:

```css
/*
Theme Name: Mamba
Theme URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/mamba-one-page-bootstrap-template-free/
Author: BootstrapMade
Author URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/
Version: 4.0.1
License URI: https://bootstrapmade.com/license/
*/
```

Comment: Now it's showing this @Levi Cole  

The package could not be installed. The theme is missing the index.php file

Comment: @KishorKumawat sounds like your theme is corrupt. I would suggest downloading it again from the source and trying again. Make sure you're uploading the full `zip` archive file.